# Simple if-else statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am writing a script that, if an array's elements are the subset of the main array, then it print PASS, otherwise, it print FAIL instead.

What should I add to my if-else statement below to make it works?

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,2]
c = [1,9]

# The Passing Scenario 

if (i in a for i in b):
 print "PASS"
else:
 print "FAIL"

# The Failing Scenario

if (i in a for i in c):
 print "PASS"
else:
 print "FAIL"
```

Comment: Could there be a list like `d = [1,1,2]`, and if so, would you consider it a "subset" of `a` or not?

Comment: Tim, you are right.. You have pointed out the loophole on my code to validate a subset. If I am not mistaken, in math, the d is not a subset of a. But for my script, I will still consider it as the "subset" of a. As it won't affect my expected result. Thanks for your reminder :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `all`.

```
# the passing scenario
if all(i in a for i in b):
    print 'PASS'
else:
    print 'FAIL'

# the failing scenario
if all(i in a for i in c):
    print 'PASS'
else:
    print 'FAIL'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solve my problem :D
Although other answers are useful too, but I am limited to this if-else structure. Thanks everyone :D

Answer (score 2):

With `set`s, it's easy:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [1,2]
>>> c = [1,9]
>>> set(b).issubset(set(a))
True
>>> set(c).issubset(set(a))
False
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the set operations like this

```
a    = [1,2,3,4,5]
b, c = [1,2],[1,9]

print set(b) <= set(a)
# True
print set(c) <= set(a)
# False
```